# CSS3 animations working only in Firefox

Tags: css, animation, cross-browser, css-transitions, css-animations

I use a lot of CSS3 transitions and animations in my webpage but they only work in Firefox and not in other browsers that i have checked, e.g. Chrome.
I use vendor prefixes but it seems to make no difference.
I also read that i must have the vendor prefixes lines before the original line, but also this try didn't give any successful result.
Here is one example of animation that is not working:

```
html {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it works but the duration of the animation is 0 seconds on other browsers, because you did not add a prefix `-webkit` to work with chrome and Safari.

So it must be

```
html{
    .....
    animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

or you could combine the `animation-duration` and `animation-name` in one css property which is `animation` so it will be

```
html{
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeftBig 1s;
    animation: fadeInLeftBig 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a -webkit specific keyframe

```
@keyframes fadeInLeftBig {

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: The lines with prefixes `-moz-` and `-o-` are useless inside a `-webkit-` keyframe.

Comment: does the order of the webkit keyframe and the original matter?

Comment: also, i don't see what is the new thing you add here? it looks the same as the original post